# Calling Javascript variable dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

below are the global variables that i have defined as....

```
global1 ="global1 contents";
global2 ="global1 contents";
```

Now i want to call this in something like this

```
console.log(global+"1") ;
```

how can we call global variable by splitting the last character?

Comment: Check this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript. Possible duplicate

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mLn2was3/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access globals by using bracket notation on the `window`:

```js
global1 = "global1 contents";
global2 = "global2 contents";

var varName = 'global';
alert(window[varName + '1']);
```

Note however that it's better practice to put your variables in to their own object to save polluting the `window`:

```js
var myObj = {
    global1: "global1 contents",
    global2: "global2 contents"
}

var varName = 'global';
alert(myObj[varName + '1']);
```